# Binding JSON response to an object returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, jackson

I am trying to bind the following JSON response from to an object using Jakson library, but it returns java.lang.NullPointerException.

**Response**

```
 {"region": 
              {"span": 
                  {"latitude_delta": 0.10262262794520893, "longitude_delta": 0.22282942}, 
          "center": {"latitude": 51.510372893357001, "longitude": -0.1108336}}, 
      "total": 246, 
      "businesses": [
           {"is_claimed": false, 
               "rating": 4.5, 
               "mobile_url": "http://m.yelp.co.uk/biz/r-garcia-and-sons-foods-and-wines-of-spain-london", 
               "rating_img_url": "http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png", 
               "review_count": 11, 
               "name": "R Garcia \u0026 Sons - Foods and Wines of Spain", 
               "snippet_image_url": "http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/photo/8xquccU5FKaFg9ZlANdOJA/ms.jpg", 
               "rating_img_url_small": "http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png", 
               "url": "http://www.yelp.co.uk/biz/r-garcia-and-sons-foods-and-wines-of-spain-london", 
               "phone": "+442072216119", 
               "snippet_text": "aka R Garcia \u0026 Son, and Cafe Garcia. Although, technically, Cafe Garcia is next door attached to their la carniceria. \n\nIt is a great Spanish grocery store...", 
               "image_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/t14haXQrAW8HMwc0RTL1jQ/ms.jpg", 
               "categories": [["Delis", "delis"], ["Spanish", "spanish"], ["Beer, Wine \u0026 Spirits", "beer_and_wine"]], 
               "display_phone": "+44 20 7221 6119", 
               "rating_img_url_large": "http://s3-media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png", 
               "id": "r-garcia-and-sons-foods-and-wines-of-spain-london", 
               "is_closed": false, 
               "location": 
                       {"city": "London", 
                   "display_address": ["248-250 Portobello Road", "Notting Hill", "London W11 1LL", "UK"], 
                   "neighborhoods": ["Notting Hill"], 
                   "postal_code": "W11 1LL", 
                   "country_code": "GB", 
                   "address": ["248-250 Portobello Road"], 
                   "state_code": "XGL"}
                        }, 
          {"is_claimed": false, "rating": 3.0, ......
```

**My Objects**

```
public class Response {
    private Region region;
    private int total;
    private List<Businesses> businesses = null;


    public Response() {
        this.businesses = new ArrayList();
    }

    public Region getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(Region region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List<Businesses> getBusinesses() {
        return businesses;
    }

    public void setBusinesses(List<Businesses> businesses) {
        this.businesses = businesses;
    }


}
```

**Businesses class**

```
public class Businesses {

    private boolean is_claimed;
    private double rating;
    private String mobile_url;
    private String rating_img_url;
    private int review_count;
    private String name;
    private String snippet_image_url;
    private String rating_img_url_small;
    private String url;
    private String phone;
    private String snippet_text;
    private String image_url;
    private String[] categories;
    private String display_phone;
    private String rating_img_url_large;
    private String id;
    private boolean is_closed;
    private Location location = null;

    public Businesses() {
       this.location = new Location();
    }

    public boolean isIs_claimed() {
        return is_claimed;
    }

    public void setIs_claimed(boolean is_claimed) {
        this.is_claimed = is_claimed;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getMobile_url() {
        return mobile_url;
    }

    public void setMobile_url(String mobile_url) {
        this.mobile_url = mobile_url;
    }

    public String getRating_img_url() {
        return rating_img_url;
    }

    public void setRating_img_url(String rating_img_url) {
        this.rating_img_url = rating_img_url;
    }

    public int getReview_count() {
        return review_count;
    }

    public void setReview_count(int review_count) {
        this.review_count = review_count;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSnippet_image_url() {
        return snippet_image_url;
    }

    public void setSnippet_image_url(String snippet_image_url) {
        this.snippet_image_url = snippet_image_url;
    }

    public String getRating_img_url_small() {
        return rating_img_url_small;
    }

    public void setRating_img_url_small(String rating_img_url_small) {
        this.rating_img_url_small = rating_img_url_small;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getSnippet_text() {
        return snippet_text;
    }

    public void setSnippet_text(String snippet_text) {
        this.snippet_text = snippet_text;
    }

    public String getImage_url() {
        return image_url;
    }

    public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
        this.image_url = image_url;
    }

    public String[] getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(String[] categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String getDisplay_phone() {
        return display_phone;
    }

    public void setDisplay_phone(String display_phone) {
        this.display_phone = display_phone;
    }

    public String getRating_img_url_large() {
        return rating_img_url_large;
    }

    public void setRating_img_url_large(String rating_img_url_large) {
        this.rating_img_url_large = rating_img_url_large;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isIs_closed() {
        return is_closed;
    }

    public void setIs_closed(boolean is_closed) {
        this.is_closed = is_closed;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

**Location Class**

```
public class Location {

    private String city;
    private String[] display_address;
    private String[] neighborhoods;
    private String postal_code;
    private String country_code;
    private String[] address;
    private String state_code;

    public Location() {
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String[] getDisplay_address() {
        return display_address;
    }

    public void setDisplay_address(String[] display_address) {
        this.display_address = display_address;
    }

    public String[] getNeighborhoods() {
        return neighborhoods;
    }

    public void setNeighborhoods(String[] neighborhoods) {
        this.neighborhoods = neighborhoods;
    }

    public String getPostal_code() {
        return postal_code;
    }

    public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
    }

    public String getCountry_code() {
        return country_code;
    }

    public void setCountry_code(String country_code) {
        this.country_code = country_code;
    }

    public String[] getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String[] address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getState_code() {
        return state_code;
    }

    public void setState_code(String state_code) {
        this.state_code = state_code;
    }


}
```

**Exception**

```
SEVERE:   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
         (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain:  
              com.myproject.restaurant.yelp.Response["businesses"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializer.java:1472)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:699)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1909)
    at com.myproject.controller.Restaurants.Yelp(Restaurants.java:93)
    at com.myproject.controller.Restaurants.find(Restaurants.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzl
SEVERE:   y.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.find(BeanPropertyMap.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:694)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:30)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    ... 86 more
```

**My binding code**

```
        InputStream response = yelp.search("spanish+food", "London");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Response responseObj= mapper.readValue(response, Response.class);
        System.err.println(">" + responseObj.getRegion().getSpan().getLatitude_delta());
```

Comment: check the structure of your JSON, I am not sure it is really representing an object from Response class. It seems that region is containing businesses and in your class they are both separated fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following JSON string:

```
"categories": [["Delis", "delis"], ["Spanish", "spanish"], ["Beer, Wine \u0026 Spirits", "beer_and_wine"]],
```

doesn't map to

```
private String[] categories;
```

The JSON `categories` is a list of list of strings while you are only mapping it to a one dimensional array of string.

Either try a two dimensional array or best is to go with `List<List<String>>`.